# Как изменить количество записей в таблице при создании прав?

Tags: yii, framework

Извините, если косноязычно, задаю вопрос. В фреймворке yii стандартно отображается по 10 записей в таблице при создании прав Crud. Где можно изменить этот параметр?

Comment: Ну, наверное, где-то тут (или где-то рядом): https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/gii/generators/crud/templates/default/_view.php

Comment: @Максим147, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).